# Implementing Play game service realtime feature

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

when i was implement quiz racer ,,play game service , i always got Game Setup Failed maybe its because i dont know how to i have tried to ask will gold store but i have not answerd ,sorry for bad grammar

Here is my code:

```
// Start the script.  The main menu needs to setup the invitation
// manager in order to detect incoming invitations.
void Start()
{
    //there is no example about HOW TO DO IT,I REALLY CONFUSED !
}
```

[1.and this is the readme but i dont know how to implement that, i really need HOW TO STEP BY STEP PLEASE ,](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/RTMP.md)

[2.here is the source code that i try to build](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/samples/QuizRacer)

i used c# script ,, please help me ,please

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Also what play game service? You'll have to add a lot more information before anyone even knows what you're talking about. Platform?

Comment: Images can't be searched or copied, and provide poor usability. Please don't use them for code snippets. I copied your code into your question, but unfortunately I still don't understand what you are asking. What service are you trying to use? Is this C#? Java? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to add some more detail and tags.

Comment: thanks alot ,,i just want to implementing play game service feature realtime multiplayer in unity3d